# I wonder reverse proxy server configuration with frontend server, api server, nginx server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm configuring reverse proxy server with nginx
Nginx.conf file is like this, location / -> front server address, location /api -> api server address.
Front server fetch from `http://${api_addr}/api` originally(before setting nginx), but now I changed api URL to `http://${nginx_addr}/api` for constructing reverse proxy server. I am wondering if it is correct to send the request directly from the front to the api address or if it is correct to send the request to the nginx address?

[reverse proxy server structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP2TL.png)

Answer (score 2):

So you're configuring a website and you want it to direct traffic to your frontend (html etc) and have an api route going to your api, if I'm reading that correctly?

You'd do it similar to this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;

    set $frontend = "frontend-stuff.com";
    set $backend = "backend.com";

    location /api {

        ## if your api backend starts at / rather than /api you'd rewrite away the /api path
        # rewrite /api/(.*) /api/$1 break;


        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        proxy_set_header Host $backend;
        proxy_pass http://$backend;

        break;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        proxy_set_header Host $frontend;
        proxy_pass http://$frontend;

        break;
    }
}
```

The variables stop nginx hitting an 'emerg' (fatal error) if a host falls down in the background between reloads; it can also be helpful with services where the frontend has a large IP range like cloudfront etc.

In the case of your frontend if you're calling something like CloudFront you'd need to force TLS1.2

```
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

`X-Forwarded-Proto https` is needed if the backend app is returning paths (.net apps use this to set paths to https etc)

> I am wondering if it is correct to send the request directly from the front to the api address or if it is correct to send the request to the nginx address?

Its best to proxy all your requests for an application via the same site config for multiple reasons, such as...

- Combined logging (easier to debug)
- Simpler to secure (set CSP and unified security headers across site)
- Easier to handle CORS for any frontend related activities (ajax/xhrf)

If you provide a bit more info I can probably pad this out

Comment: Thank you.
eg) frontend's code: not `await axios.get("http://${api_addr}/api") ~~`  but `await axios.get("http://${nginx_addr}/api") ~~`.  The latter one is you want to say, right?

Comment: Yes you'd use the nginx route if you were calling using axios in the browser as its being routed /api > your API via nginx. If it's axios server side (API calling itself for some reason) then you'd probably just use localhost rather than go out of the network and back in.

Comment: If you had a site, say turnip.com and you'd routed / to your frontend S3 bucket and /API to a docker container or simple app, from a browsers perspective there's only turnip.com the underlying routing is a black box, opaque to the client. So the webpage from S3 calling /api would all be loaded from and calling the same domain.

Comment: Thank you, I got it.

Comment: @ChrisMcKee that means that you could expose your backend API only to the Nginx web server and it would route Axios requests executed in the browser frontend code to the backend although the browser cant reach the backend api?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli Not sure what you're trying to say. 
NGinx should be your edge, the browser will go via nginx for all requests, you can route the requests using "locations" to any underlying storage or api endpoint.

Comment: @ChrisMcKee YES! That's exactly what I did, it works locally but when uploaded it receives 502, 404 or 200 depending on the frontend request route (all preceded by `/api` and is the only nginx location declared), the only difference I've noticed is in request method, headers and request body data. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to always query the Nginx endpoint and not the specific port. By directly querying the specific api port, you are completely bypassing the server routing service and could therefore accidentally overload your api endpoint if not careful.

By routing everything through the Nginx server, you ensure that your api service remains healthy and works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So front request  via nginx endpoint rather than communicate front with api for configuring reverse proxy server? Should frontend do like this? `await axios.get("http://${nginx_addr}/api")`?

Comment: Yes that's correct. If you're running the stack within Docker then you can even use ```await axios.get('/api')```!

Comment: Yes, I run this within docker, but I don't understand why it is possible to use `axios.get('/api')`. Please explain why it can be?